# Когда стоит использовать приставку наи-?

Tags: словообразование

Когда стоит использовать приставку наи-, а когда можно обойтись без неё? Чем, например, отличаются слова "лучший" и "наилучший"?

Comment: Вопрос не имеет конкретики, где бы можно было видеть проблему. Похоже, общие сведения Вас тоже не устраивают.

Answer (score 1):

1) Из словаря:

**НАИЛУ́ЧШИЙ,** наилучшая, наилучшее (книжн.). Самый лучший, самый **предпочтительный, представляющий преимущества сравнительно с другими**. Наилучший способ. Наилучший сорт. Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков.

Ключевое слово: **сравнительно с другими**. Поэтому при употреблении приставки НАИ этот смысл должен быть обозначен. Для сравнения: (1) Это лучший способ лечения.  (2) Это наилучший из известных сейчас способ лечения.  Второй пример более информативный.

2)  Значение приставки НАИ связано с ее этимологией

**Этимология приставки НАИ** (словарь Фасмера)

https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/%D0%BD/%D0%BD%D0%B0

Приставка на- имеет также усилительное знач.: на́больно «очень б.», на́больший, на́крепко, на́скоро (Преобр. I, 586). Образование **превосходной степ.** в цслав. с приставкой **наи-**, ст.-слав. наи-, болг. най-, сербохорв. наj-, словен. nа-, naj-, чеш. ná-, nej-, польск. nа-, naj-, в.-луж. naj- содержит на в соединении **с дейктической част. -i-**

**Примечание.** Дейктическими словами называются слова, для которых соответствия во внеязыковом мире определяются каждый раз по-разному, в зависимости от обстоятельств, при которых это слово было употреблено. Ближайший синоним: указательный. Дейктическими, к примеру, являются  местоимения ты, я.

Получается, что  приставка НАИ состоит из приставки НА, выражающей превосходную степени) и дейктического (указательного) И.  Но тогда слова с приставкой НАИ должны соотноситься с **конкретной** ситуацией, то есть не надо искать в них **абсолютного** значения.

3) Словообразование

В словах с приставкой  ***НАИ***  превосходная степень слова **выражена дважды**: с помощью приставки *НАИ* и соответствующих суффиксов, также обозначающих превосходную степень, например: строгий  — строж/айш/ий  —  наи/строж/айш/ий.

Также: *лучший* (превосходная степень) — *наилучший* (лучший из лучших).

4) **О приставке НАИ**

(Виноградов. Русск. язык, с. 253). http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vinogradov.php?id=nai_&vol=3

Приставка наи- вообще в литературном языке присоединяется лишь к формам на -ейший, -айший и -ший, например: наистрожайший запрет, наиглупейшее предложение, наилучший, наименьший, наивысший, наисложнейший и т. п. (В приставке наи- обычно за Ломоносовым, а иностранцы вслед за Vondrak (Vergleichende slav. Grammatik, B. II. Formenlehre und Syntax, 1908, S. 74) видят заимствование из польского языка. Но K. Meyer не без основания указывает на употребление (рядом с префиксом все-) этого префикса в церковнославянском языке (ср. все- в дореволюционном официально-канцелярском языке: всепокорнейший слуга, всеподданнейший отчет, всемилостивейший государь и т. п.)

Сочетания наи- с формой положительной степени (ср. наисильный; наиглавный; у Даля — наивелик (Толковый словарь, 2, с. 1091) **не входят в норму** литературного употребления.

Answer (score 0):

*Наилучший* — самый лучший; лучший из лучших.

*Наи-* используется для акцентуации значения *самый-самый*. Даже когда слово в некоторой степени уже это подразумевает, приставка придаёт особый эффект.
Примеры из словаря:
*Наилучший способ обработки.

Наилучшие результаты.

Всего наилучшего.*

Answer (score 0):

"**Наилучший**" означает "**самый лучший**" (просто "лучший" может также заменять сравнительную степень прилагательного "хороший", что в ряде контекстов требует дополнительного уточнения), но **не всегда** может его заменить. Нельзя, например, сказать "*наилучший фигурист* (этого тренера, чемпионата или из когда-либо живших)" вместо "самый лучший". Это прилагательное часто имеет эмоциональную окраску и обычно применяется с абстрактными существительными, например: *наилучшие пожелания*, *наилучший вариант*, *решение*. Не так просто придумать и контекст, в котором выражение "лучший из лучших" (часто трактуемое как синоним "наилучшего") безболезненно заменилось бы на "наилучший".

Answer (score 0):

Если, например, идёт текст про футболистов: "...Василий Забивалкин лучший нападающий", мы сразу поймём, что он лучший **из** **футбольных нападающих**, и, разумеется, Майкл Джордан не уступит ему в баскетболе. А вот если употребить "**наи**лучший", без конкретного уточнения в чём, то слово "**наи**лучший" приобретёт слишком глобальное значение.