# Наиужасающее — наиужасающееще

Tags: орфография

Правильно ли написано это слова, которое значит 'более чем просто ужасающий'?

> Событие было это просто **наиужасающееще**.

Comment: наиужас**ней**шее..

Comment: @Буратино Ваш пример образован от прилагательного _ужасный_, а примеры Леопольда — от причастия _ужасающий_.

Comment: @Максим Ужасающий - это причастие, у причастий нет сравнительных форм. Ужасающий может выступать в значении прилагательного, но это всё же причастие.

Comment: Каких сравнительных форм? Не тупите, к причастию просто добавляют приставку НАИ-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь **нет правильных слов.**

Дело в том, что приставка ***НАИ*** используется при образовании нового слова от превосходной степени **прилагательного.**

Ужасающий  – это причастие, у него **нет превосходной степени.** Также для образования новых слов не используются **причастные формы** прилагательных  с суффиксом ЮЩ: *настоящий, грядущий, будущий.*

**О приставке *НАИ***

Современный толковый словарь русского языка **Ефремовой**

**Префикс.** Формообразовательная единица, образующая имена прилагательные со значением признака, который характеризуется **высшей степенью проявления качества**, названного словами - обычно формами превосходной степени, от которых соответствующие имена прилагательные образованы (наикрепча́йший, наилу́чший, наиумне́йший, наиху́дший и т.п.).

**Тема обсуждалась на форуме:**

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458002/Когда-стоит-использовать-приставку-наи](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458002/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149199/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.